# How I will add html tag double curly braces in blade file laravel

Tags: php, laravel, echo, laravel-blade

$slider->details value is slider heading  in database, however,  is not being rendered.

```
I have solved it by php echo (<?php echo $slider->details; ?>) but I want to use
```

the blade syntax instead.

Comment: $slider->details value is<h1> slider heading</h1> in database

Comment: you can use {!! html tags here.  !!}

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue or is `$slider->details` still not rendering correctly? If it has answered your question please may you mark it as accepted :)

Comment: If $slider->details contains html tags then you have to use {!! $slider->details !!} to show data, other wise simply use {{ $slider->details }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks.

If you don't want the data to be escaped then you need to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`:

```
{!! $slider->details !!}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) for displaying data.